# Facebook API on iOS; detect whether user is signed in without triggering a dialog?

Tags: ios, facebook

I have an iOS app that uses Facebook Connect via Facebook's API.

If I call the isSessionValid method on the Facebook object after the user has authenticated, it returns true, as expected. I can also make it return true when the app launches if I store and retrieve the access token and expiration date in the app defaults.

What I'm looking for is a way to determine, at the time the app is first launched by a user who just installed it, whether they are signed in to Facebook or not. I want to do this without triggering a permissions dialog. Is it possible?

The idea is to customize the first screen based on whether the user is signed in to Facebook or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can call the isSessionValid method in Facebook.m which does this

```
- (BOOL)isSessionValid {
return (self.accessToken != nil && self.expirationDate != nil
        && NSOrderedDescending == [self.expirationDate compare:[NSDate date]]);

  }
```

With your Facebook object

Comment: This function always returns false the first time the app launches, regardless of whether the user is actually logged in to Facebook. This makes sense since the app hasn't yet stored a token and would not otherwise have any way to know what's going on with the FB app. It's likely that it's not possible to do what I want, but I want to make sure before I give up on it.